# Sidebar shopping cart lists items differently magento

Tags: javascript, css, magento, cart, sidebar

I have a sidebar cart on the website that has a product in there, it´s a test product ( simple product ) and a Accu ( simple product, but bundeld under the test product ) so if added, they both get added to the shopping cart, and when I hover over it, it lists them differently, I'm pretty new to magento, and I've tried working with the JS that lists them ( adds odd and even to it ) but this doesn't do anything with the result, the bundled product ends up looking different.

edit: I'll clarify: The products are both added, as should, but they are displayed differently ( as, the image is on the right side instead of the left, I'd like this to be the same for all products in there.

A push in the right way would be awesome, as I said I'm kind of new, but eager to learn.

Link to example image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JICw.jpg

If there is more info needed, I'm happy to supply that, thanks in advance.

Comment: If you add both the bundled and the simple product, they will be both displayed in teh shopping cart.

Comment: WHat do you want exactly to achieve?

Comment: I've updated my question, basically I want them all to be the same as the bottom one, no matter what kind of product it is, so I want all the images to the left, text to the right. as the shown test product is. My apologies for being unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Change the bundled product **main image**.
2. Edit the sidebar cart phtml or css file in order to display all images on the same side.

Comment: The bundled product main image is the current image, but this might be too small you mean?

I can't find a css for the sidebar specific, could you point me in a direction? I can acces the phtml, but that doesn't say anything about a different build up for grouped/bundled products.

Comment: I think I got it, because it has no url, as it's not individual approachable, it shows a different way. Is that a good assumption?

Comment: I might add, the location for that file was the default.phtml of sidebar. Thanks for your help, you made my day, any advice on how I can find this out faster/more efficient in the future?

Comment: Turn on template path hints in teh backend so you can see the location of all phtml files that are used to generate the page: System->Configuration->Developer->Template Path Hints. You must choose a shop for 'Current configuration scope' on top let dropdown in the backend.